Homology with local coefficients examples
I'm learning about homology with local coefficients for the first time from the Davis-Kirk book on algebraic topology, but I'm having trouble since they don't give a single elementary example worked out. I'd like to understand what the homology with coefficients in a local system $A_{\rho}$ associated to $\rho$ a representation of the fundamental group of $X$ is, for some elementary examples of $X$ like: $S^1$, a wedge $S^1 \vee \cdots \vee S^1$, and something non-compact like a plane punctured $n$ times.
Could you help or provide a reference with a nice treatment of a few examples? Thanks!

I would suggest looking at another book such as Hatcher's algebraic topology.  Munkre's "Elements of..." is a better math book in my tastes, however.

Try Spanier ${}{}{}{}{}{}$ or jump into the deep end with sheaf theory .. (cohomology with local coefficients, in a sense)

It's not quite clear what you are asking. Do you not know how to compute the homology, given $\rho$? Do you know how to compute it, but you want some simple examples to work on? As currently written, your post sounds like you want a little minicourse on the topic, which is a little unfocussed for this site. If you could ask a more focussed mathematical question, that would improve your post.

How do you define "a nice treatment" in your final question?  What's "nice" is subjective (opinion-based)

How much topology do you know? For instance, would the words "consider $K(G,1)$" mean anything to you?
